# Symfony 3 inject service into controller

Tags: symfony

I'm using symfony 3.1.7 and I have problems with inject services into a controller, my english is bad I believe that it is better if I show all the code.

**The error:**

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   ...Bundle\Controller\AdminController::__construct() must
>   implement interface
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface, none given,
>   called in /......./project/var/cache/dev/classes.php on line 2512

This is my code:

**GenericRestController**

```
namespace MyCoreBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
use MyCoreBundle\Handler\GenericRestHandlerInterface as Generic;
/** other uses like FOSRestController **/

/**
 * Class GenericRestController
 */
abstract class GenericRestController extends FOSRestController
{
  protected $handler;
  protected $container;

  public function __construct(Container $container,Generic $handler)
  {
      $this->container = $container;
      $this->handler = $handler;
  }

  /** other methods like get, post, put, etc **/
}
```

**AdminController**

```
namespace ...Bundle\Controller;
use MyCoreBundle\Controller\GenericRestController;

class AdminController extends GenericRestController
{

}
```

### ***RESOLVED***

The solution was change the routes as Cerad says.

Oficial documentation

**services.yml**

```
services:
    app.hello_controller:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\HelloController
```

**routing.yml**

```
hello:
    path:     /hello
    defaults: { _controller: app.hello_controller:indexAction }
```

Thanks mtaqi and Cerad

Comment: did u see what `php app/console container:debug` lists shows?

Comment: Need to adjust your route to use the controller as a service.  As it stands right now, the controller is being instantiated by the controller resolver using it's class name and not the container.  Check the docs defining controllers as services carefully.  And when you get it running, remove the container from the constructor and adjust your service definition to call setContainer.  Things will be a bit cleaner.

Comment: You are right @Cerad !! thank both for the help!!

Comment: Please don't edit post to inject response. Put your answer below and accept it. Otherwise, some people like me spent time to read your resolved problem ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was change the routes as Cerad says.

Oficial documentation

**services.yml**

```
services:
    app.hello_controller:
    class: AppBundle\Controller\HelloController
```

**routing.yml**

```
hello:
   path:     /hello
   defaults: { _controller: app.hello_controller:indexAction }
```

Sorry for the delay and thanks!